# How to match a regex only if it matches exactly

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to devise a regex in JS that matches a string containing 7-14 consecutive digits.

I have the following

```
var regex = /[^a-zA-Z]\d{6,15}[^a-zA-Z]/g;
```

But when I have test it with the following string, it fails.

```
var test = "111222333444555666";
```

It accepts the matches the first 14 digits, which is not what I want. I want to match only if my regex is not surrounded by other digits and not surround by chars.

I could naively plop `[^a-zA-Z\d]` on the end of the regex, but I feel like there's an easier way.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
erip

Comment: "I'm trying to devise a regex" split ?

Comment: `test.match(regex);`

Comment: If I understand right, you could use anchors to the beginning/end of input, like this: `/^\d{7,14}$/` This would ensure the input contains only the 7 - 14 digits and nothing more.

Comment: If you want it *"and not surround by chars"*, why do you have `[^a-zA-Z]`?

Comment: Does JS `^` not mean the same thing as PCRE `^`?

Comment: if **outside** a character class (`[]`) it means `Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»`

Comment: Pedro, it's inside the character list..

Comment: It means **different** for any of the characters inside the character class

Comment: Why don't post a clear sample of input/output . i.e.: "__i have this__" and  "__I need this__" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` will check a number is not preceded nor followed by `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

**Code**

```js
var regex = /\b\d{7,14}\b/g
var test = "abc 111222333444555666 1234 123456789 1234567890123 12345678xyz";

// print all matches
while ((m = regex.exec(test)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    document.writeln("<br />Match: " + m[0]);
}
```

Comment: Because `+`, `-` and `.` are not word characters. Hence, `\b` there will only match next to a word character like `c`.

Comment: Then use the opposite, `\B` matches non-word boundaries `/\B[-+]\d{7,14}\b/`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to match only if my regex is not surrounded by other digits and
>   not surround by chars.

```
if (/\b[\da-z]{7,14}\b/.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

---

**Regex Explanation**

```
\b[\da-z]{7,14}\b

Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
Match a single character present in the list below «[\da-z]{7,14}»
   Between 7 and 14 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{7,14}»
   A “digit” «\d»
   A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
```